# Time stamped data set analysis in R

Tags: r, time, rstudio

I need to perform a time stamped event analysis to find out results from the given data set that what set of `error_codes` leads to a critical error code. Let's say **54645** is a critical error code so I need to know what are the error codes causing this error. My dataset has 1,59,600 rows.

```
id date_time             error_codes
1  2015-04-16 16:25:33   54654
1  2015-04-16 16:25:34   55466
2  2015-04-16 16:30:00   54656
1  2015-04-17 17:25:33   654535
2  2015-04-17 17:30:33   5466456
2  2015-04-17 17:40:22   45646
3  2015-04-17 18:35:34   56464
1  2015-04-18 00:18:35   54645
3  2015-04-18 04:25:33   545646
..........................
```

I need my results to be like:

```
{54654}-1sec-{55466}-1day1hour-{654535}----6hour53mins2sec---->{54645} Supp=0.02
```

This result shows that these 3 error codes leads to a critical error code which has a support of 2 % from the dataset that means if we have 100 rows in dataset this pattern is seen two times. Time has a tolerance of 1min
so if any pattern like this occur having a slight difference of time should be considered.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I guess many will be glad to help. However, this is no free coding service. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i am able to find which error codes are coming together using arules package but i am not finding any solution to find time difference between codes
any solution of doing association by putting corresponding value of time from another data frame would be good